# How to do pure javascript animation just like the jquery

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I am familiar with jQuery but not in javascript. Here I have a jQuery rendered animation which needs to be done using javascript. I am stuck and to be frank I don't known where to start. Here is my **[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/hcx9bkub/)**. This example needs to be rendered in pure javascript. Can anyone one assist me how things works on with javascript.

**MARKUP**

```
<div class="clck">Click</div>
<div class="modal">
    <div class="head">Head</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal {
    width: 100px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    background: orange;
    bottom: 0;
}
.clck {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: red;
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 2;
    margin:auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.head {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: why not use css3 animations ..

Comment: It has browser compatible issues

Comment: Have a look at the jQuery source https://github.com/jquery/jquery

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) can assist you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use javascript to alter the class names and use CSS to perform the actual animations. This updated fiddle should help but the class targeting is as follows.

http://jsfiddle.net/hcx9bkub/12/

```
var c = document.getElementsByClassName('clck')[0];
    c.onclick = function () {
        var m = document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0];
            m.className = m.className + ' active';
    };
```

Edited to update the link to the correct fiddle version, and updated to use variables.